# How to link a file to an entry(collection type) in Strapi V4?

Tags: javascript, html, strapi, web-development-server, react-fullstack

I am using Strapi V4 to save all the data of my form. In my strapi architecture there is a file/image field and others are text field. I want to link this image and other entries. currently when I submit my form it creates entry but file field is remained empty but file is uploaded to media library, they are not linked to each other. please guide me how can I make it possible that file should be linked to the entry.

here is my js code:

```
const createQuatation = async (formData) => {

fetch(SERVER_URL + '/', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
})
    .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            console.log(response.json());
            console.log('File uploaded successfully!');
            $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('hide');
            getQuotationList();
        } else {
            console.log('File upload failed!');
            $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('hide');
            getQuotationList();
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    });
```

}

```
document.getElementById("saveButton").addEventListener("click", function () {
    const formData = new FormData();

const formElements = formElement.elements;

const data = {};

for (let i = 0; i < formElements.length; i++) {
    const currentElement = formElements[i];
    if (!['submit', 'file'].includes(currentElement.type)) {
        data[currentElement.name] = currentElement.value;
    } else if (currentElement.type === 'file') {
        for (let i = 0; i < currentElement.files.length; i++) {
            const file = currentElement.files[i];
            formData.append(`files.${currentElement.name}`, file, file.name,);
            formData.append('ref', 'api::quotation.quotation');
            formData.append('refId', 14);
            formData.append('field', 'file');
        }
    }
}

formData.append('data', JSON.stringify(data));
for (const value of formData.values()) {
    console.log(value);
}

createQuatation(formData);
```

});[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're mixing to separate procedures:

- if you want to create a new entry with a file, then just append the file, no ref or refId needed. Just mention the field in:

```
formData.append(`files.${name_of_the_field}`, file, file.name);
```

- if you want to update an existing entry with a different file, then you'll need the ref, refId etc. in the formData. RefId should be a string. Just send the formData with the file as the body, and nothing else:

```
await fetch('/api/upload', {
   method: 'post',
   body: new FormData(e.target)
});
```